# How to keep dropdown list from one view to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

in my controller, I have Create actions for Get and Post.

On Get action, I load dropdown data list and show it in view, while I keep only value of selected item. Then I click on submit and call Post action of Create and logic is finished.

But when I call Create action, and model isn't valid, I go back to Get. And here starts the problem, because my dropdown data no longer exists. So I can on my Create action, when model is not valid, again load dropdown data from database, but my idea is to keep and move dropdown data list from Get to Post action, like I sometimes did with "hidden input id". But i have no idea what html tag or helper use for data List.

Something like:

```
<Select type="hidden" value="@Model.DataList">
```

Comment: I think "again load dropdown data from database" is a clean way, because  you can use tag or helper for data List selected one, cannot send back the whole list. You also can use other ways, but that need  more code than your code of "again load dropdown data from database" .

Comment: Yea it seems like i will go that way, just load select on each load.

Answer (score 0):

I think that transfert the DropDownlist elements between get and post actions is not the right approach. It could make the server calls too long, especially if you have several elements.

I suggest you to create a cache (session cache for example) of your DropDownList items and use it during the get action.
With this system, when you have an invalid model, the get will reload the data without calling the database.